# Dialogflow empty fulfillment message

Tags: dialogflow-es

Sometime Dialogflow is sending an empty response for an Intent defined in an agent. I can see in the training phrase that the intent is matched with the query however the "Raw Interaction" Log section for that message shows that "fulfillmentMessages" message array does not contain the text.

Fulfillment is not enabled for this

```
"fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "[{\"type\":0,\"speech\":\"\"}]"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Here is the picture from the **History section**. The agent does not send any response after the user says headquarters.

[image]

In the **Training Section**, you can see that the headquarters phrase is successfully matched with the intent.

[image]

And this is the response section of the intent. The fulfillment for the intent is not enabled (However, I am using Webhook for few intents)

[image]

**6.5.ProvidesJobTitle.6.6.AskPrReleaseDate** intent JSON:

```
{
  "id": "bba486d7-b06e-42c7-92a4-3b4bfea75dbd",
  "name": "6.5.ProvidesJobTitle.6.6.AskPrReleaseDate",
  "auto": true,
  "contexts": [
    "awaiting_job_title"
  ],
  "responses": [
    {
      "resetContexts": false,
      "affectedContexts": [
        {
          "name": "awaiting_pr_release_date",
          "parameters": {},
          "lifespan": 1
        }
      ],
      "parameters": [
        {
          "id": "5f93100d-bd58-4adc-a2a2-1fb9e73b411f",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@sys.any",
          "name": "Spokesperson1title",
          "value": "$Spokesperson1title",
          "isList": false
        },
        {
          "id": "0d55ea53-e0cf-406b-99db-3a1f84001b9c",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@sys.any",
          "name": "Organisation1premises",
          "value": "#awaiting_job_title.Organisation1premises",
          "isList": false
        },
        {
          "id": "8f35a4c0-414f-4302-8bbc-0fc92f09c651",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@sys.geo-city",
          "name": "organizationCity",
          "value": "#awaiting_job_title.organizationCity",
          "isList": false
        },
        {
          "id": "d32610a1-f769-4193-ae2e-ad1c1ce32f4d",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@sys.geo-state",
          "name": "organizationState",
          "value": "#awaiting_job_title.organizationState",
          "isList": false
        },
        {
          "id": "29f388c1-78d7-40f4-8d55-4510241a2f8b",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@sys.any",
          "name": "organizationType",
          "value": "#awaiting_job_title.organizationType",
          "isList": false
        },
        {
          "id": "36b76fd7-d16e-478e-8263-3fcc8e59c8a3",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@sys.given-name",
          "name": "Organization1name",
          "value": "#awaiting_job_title.Organization1name",
          "isList": false
        },
        {
          "id": "389f1b1b-537c-4bdf-8b23-49754cc1f81b",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@sys.email",
          "name": "Email",
          "value": "#awaiting_job_title.Email",
          "isList": false
        },
        {
          "id": "36b005e6-c84d-419d-862c-8a1ab7f13d1b",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@sys.given-name",
          "name": "Inputuserfirstname",
          "value": "#awaiting_job_title.Inputuserfirstname",
          "isList": false
        },
        {
          "id": "fbece295-0c67-412d-8497-630d5eb0d7a8",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@sys.given-name",
          "name": "Spokesperson1firstname",
          "value": "#awaiting_job_title.Spokesperson1firstname",
          "isList": false
        },
        {
          "id": "e2cca15a-547f-4d96-89c0-1cf8cf579e6a",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@sys.given-name",
          "name": "Spokesperson1lastname",
          "value": "#awaiting_job_title.Spokesperson1lastname",
          "isList": false
        },
        {
          "id": "7a679b6a-212b-4c78-a7d6-50d8d13e7469",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@sys.geo-country",
          "name": "organizationCountry",
          "value": "#awaiting_job_title.organizationCountry",
          "isList": false
        }
      ],
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "Thank you. What date do you plan to send your press release to media outlets and put it on your website?"
        }
      ],
      "defaultResponsePlatforms": {},
      "speech": []
    }
  ],
  "priority": 500000,
  "webhookUsed": false,
  "webhookForSlotFilling": false,
  "fallbackIntent": false,
  "events": [],
  "userSays": [
    {
      "id": "20d6fbd6-b642-4b18-a363-c4b1bace9cff",
      "data": [
        {
          "text": "The job title is ",
          "userDefined": false
        },
        {
          "text": "CEO",
          "alias": "Spokesperson1title",
          "meta": "@sys.any",
          "userDefined": true
        },
        {
          "text": ".",
          "userDefined": false
        }
      ],
      "isTemplate": false,
      "count": 0,
      "isAuto": false
    },
    {
      "id": "4c35c803-eba5-4634-ad76-63b4b7299ccd",
      "data": [
        {
          "text": "CEO",
          "alias": "Spokesperson1title",
          "meta": "@sys.any",
          "userDefined": true
        },
        {
          "text": ".",
          "userDefined": false
        }
      ],
      "isTemplate": false,
      "count": 0,
      "isAuto": false
    },
    {
      "id": "0277f9ee-8579-4464-b890-4e803d161f73",
      "data": [
        {
          "text": "His title is ",
          "userDefined": false
        },
        {
          "text": "Software Engineer",
          "alias": "Spokesperson1title",
          "meta": "@sys.any",
          "userDefined": true
        },
        {
          "text": ".",
          "userDefined": false
        }
      ],
      "isTemplate": false,
      "count": 0,
      "isAuto": false
    },
    {
      "id": "b5cadb93-b7d9-4aa7-be3a-19c28ca53da3",
      "data": [
        {
          "text": "Engineer",
          "alias": "Spokesperson1title",
          "meta": "@sys.any",
          "userDefined": true
        }
      ],
      "isTemplate": false,
      "count": 0,
      "isAuto": false
    },
    {
      "id": "80231779-714b-465d-838e-5f8b6887e4ec",
      "data": [
        {
          "text": "His job title is ",
          "userDefined": false
        },
        {
          "text": "CTO",
          "alias": "Spokesperson1title",
          "meta": "@sys.any",
          "userDefined": true
        },
        {
          "text": ".",
          "userDefined": false
        }
      ],
      "isTemplate": false,
      "count": 0,
      "isAuto": false
    },
    {
      "id": "b2f5c478-e886-467c-9282-092587c5183b",
      "data": [
        {
          "text": "He is the ",
          "userDefined": false
        },
        {
          "text": "CTO",
          "alias": "Spokesperson1title",
          "meta": "@sys.any",
          "userDefined": true
        },
        {
          "text": " of the organization.",
          "userDefined": false
        }
      ],
      "isTemplate": false,
      "count": 0,
      "isAuto": false
    },
    {
      "id": "6aff6b93-0ac8-40f9-be99-b08e074b2277",
      "data": [
        {
          "text": "CEO",
          "alias": "Spokesperson1title",
          "meta": "@sys.any",
          "userDefined": true
        }
      ],
      "isTemplate": false,
      "count": 0,
      "isAuto": false
    }
  ],
  "followUpIntents": [],
  "liveAgentHandoff": false,
  "endInteraction": false,
  "templates": []
}
```

Comment: On the main dialog flow page, can you click intents and then click download for the intent you call "6.5 .ProvidesJobTitle 6.6.AskPrReleaseDate".  This will produce a JSON file.  Can you then attach that JSON file as a link in your question?

Comment: JSON added @Kolban

Comment: However, the output message (response) of the `6.4.ProvidesPresence.6.5.AskJobTitle` is not showing.